# How to use take a Photo in MS-Access in Vista or later - maybe MediaCapture or DirectShow

Tags: vba, ms-access, webcam, ms-access-2013

How to use MediaCapture or DirectShow API in MS-Access?  As WIA is outdated for cameras.

WIA examples exist but not MediaCapture or DirectShow

I almost never use VBA but need to capture a photo using Access 2013.
I have found a .net example by MS that looks like it will do want I need, how to get it to work in VBA in Access?

```
      ' Using Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI API to capture a photo 
        Dim dialog As New CameraCaptureUI()  
        Dim file As StorageFile = Await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo)
```

MS says: [WIA does not support cameras in Windows Vista or later.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630191(v=vs.85).aspx)
There are lots of good examples of how to use WIA with access, but am not finding anything for MediaCapture/DirectShow API

### .net MediaCapture example:

Main File:  CapturePhoto.xaml.vb  in

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CameraCaptureUI-Sample-845a53ac/sourcecode?fileId=43599&pathId=1212418128

### .net DirectShow example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671407/Camera-Net-Library

This explains how to make available in MS Access as a DLL:
[A Simple C# DLL - how do I call it from Excel, Access, VBA, VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170794/a-simple-c-sharp-dll-how-do-i-call-it-from-excel-access-vba-vb6)

Comment: What operating system are you using? (I assume windows 8 +)

Comment: @Brad It is 8.1 Pro - but expect to upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140725/take-a-snapshot-with-a-webcam-from-ms-access-form/32190141#32190141

Comment: @brad using "Shell" works, but is not ideal, mostly because of detecting when the user is done with taking pictures. Any other options? One way would be DirectShow. i.e Create a DLL that works with MS access using this .net code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671407/Camera-Net-Library

Comment: With this approach you need to watch the `Camera Roll` folder for changes. Maybe a timer which uses FileSystemObject and caches the results then compares? It is a little easier when I did this in C# which can raise an event when a folder changes. Maybe there is a way in VBA but not sure right now. I have tried to use the DirectShow path and it is just way more complicated than it needs to be. Granted, the opening-the-camera-app route does take some user instruction (when you have finished taking your picture swipe back to your Access app) but seems like a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @brad Decided to open up a Form with just a "Taking Photos - done" on it. Then launch the camera, then pull any new pictures from Camera Roll.  To pull the pictures, this gets the pictures dir =CreateObject("Shell.Application").NameSpace(&H27).Self.Path