# take a snapshot with a webcam from ms access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

i need to take a snapshot with webcam when someone press a button in access form.
Is it possible?
i know how open a program from access but i'm stuck on how to trigger the event

```
the code
Private Sub Command1_Click()

   Dim stAppName As String

   stAppName = "C:\Program Files\myapp"
   Call Shell(stAppName, 1)

End Sub
```

now let's say the snapshot trigger by f12 key in the app
how do i get the f12 key to click automatically

Answer (score 1):

ok i got it

if any one want to know here is the method

1.by 2 macros "runapplication" & "sendkeys"

with "runapplication" just put the path of the app

with "sendkeys" just put the command  SendKeys "{yorkey}"

by the way you need to press show all command in the the toolbar

or you can do it in vba code

Answer (score 1):

You could try this if you are in windows 8/8.1

```
Dim cameraPath As String
cameraPath = "shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MoCamera_cw5n1h2txyewy!Microsoft.Camera"
Shell "explorer " & cameraPath
```

Comment: tnx for your answer. but i solved it by to macros "runapplication" & "sendkeys"